# No simple discontinuity in $f'$. Can we prove it with a double-indexed sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I have been trying to prove that a derivative does not have a simple discontinuity (that is, right-left limits exist, yet at least one is not equal to the value of the function), but a solution I've come with uses a technique that I am dubious of.

> If $f$ is differentiable in $[a,b]$, then $f'$ does not have a simple discontinuity at any point.

Assume $t_n\to x^-$. For each fixed $n$, let $y_{n,m}\to t_n$ with $t_n<y_{n,m}<x$. And assume $f'(t_n)\to\alpha\neq f'(x)$. For a fixed $n$, we have
\begin{align*}
  \frac{f(y_{n,m})-f(x)}{y_{n,m}-x}&\to\frac{f(t_n)-f(x)}{t_n-x},\\
  \frac{f(y_{n,m})-f(t_n)}{y_{n,m}-t_n}&\to f'(t_n).
 \end{align*}
If we look at $y_{n,n}$ and let $n\to\infty$, we see that
\begin{align*}
  \frac{f(y_{n,n})-f(x)}{y_{n,n}-x}&\to f'(x),\\
  \frac{f(y_{n,n})-f(t_n)}{y_{n,n}-t_n}&\to\alpha.
 \end{align*}
But $t_n\to x$ and $f(t_n)\to f(x)$, and we have a contradiction. Deal similarly with $t_n\to x^+$.

I stated that for a fixed $n$ two limits exist for some two expressions, which is ok. Then, I use a diagonal approach to conclude what the previous expressions limit to if we let $n\to\infty$, yet this is where some incertitude is. Is this conclusion legitimate? Basically, I used the limits of $f'(t_n)$ and $\frac{f(t_n)-f(x)}{t_n-x}$. If this step is at least plausible (and very likely can be shown to be valid), the last step where I infer a contradiction concerns me even more.

Comment: No, it isn't valid. $t_n \to x$ and $f(t_n) \to f(x)$ is not sufficient to show that $\frac{f(y_{n,n})-f(x)}{y_{n,n}-x}$ and $\frac{f(y_{n,n})-f(t_n)}{y_{n,n}-t_n}$ converge to the same limit. In fact, it would not contradict anything you've established if $y_{n,n} = t_n$ for all $n$, which would make the latter expression undefined for all $n$.

Comment: You might want to choose an $\epsilon > 0$, and find a $\delta$ such that for all $t$ with $-\delta < t-x<\delta$ we have $(f'(x)-\epsilon)|t - x| < f(t) - f(x) < (f'(x) + \epsilon)|t-x|$ and we what you can figure out about $f'(t)$ for $t$ in that neighborhood.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, so, the diagonal conclusion is illegal, too, even when $y_{n,m}\neq t_n$ for all $n$ and $m$? But why? In hand-wavy language, for large $n$, $f'(t_n)$ is closer to $\alpha$ (as we assumed), and for large $m$, $\frac{f(y_{n,m})-f(t_n)}{y_{n,m}-t_n}$ is closer to $f'(t_n)$ (as it is established), so it seems like it can be proved using epsilon-deltas with labor.

Comment: It is not "illegal". There is no "legal" vs "illegal" in Math. The standard in Math is "It can be shown to work" vs "It cannot be shown to work". Your diagonal argument fails exactly because you have not shown that it must work. You have assumed part of your argument, and I am pointing that out to you. Though in fact you were already vaguely aware of it, as that is what  inspired you to ask the question. You were hoping someone would shore up that part of the argument. I'm telling you no. If you think you can prove it, go ahead and try. But just assuming it works doesn't cut it in Math.